# How to turn raw data into matrix with row and column using python?

Tags: python, matrix, dataframe

For example,
I have raw data like:

```
Jim  Age  38
Rose Height 5'8
Jim  Salary 60000
Jim  Height 5'10
Rose Salary 40000
Rose Age   25
```

How could I turn into dataframe using python:

```
     Age  Height Salary
Jim  38   5'10   60000
Rose 25   5'8    40000
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want your matrix to be printed out directly as in your post or do you need a matrix-like structure to hold your data?

Comment: I need as matrix-like structure, or dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `pandas` data frame, you can use `pivot` function:

```
df.pivot(0, 1, 2)

#1     Age  Height  Salary
#0          
# Jim   38    5'10   60000
#Rose   25     5'8   40000
```

*Data Used*:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Jim  Age  38
Rose Height 5'8
Jim  Salary 60000
Jim  Height 5'10
Rose Salary 40000
Rose Age   25"""), sep = "\s+", header=None)
```